# How can a gas in a cyllinder do work if net force is 0?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, ideal-gas

If I have a cylinder filled with an ideal gas and a piston and if the pressure of the gas is greater than the surrounding pressure how can the gas do work if the net force on the gas is 0 i.e. the forces acting on the gas are the force due to the piston and the sides and bottom of the container which all cancel out so the net force is 0 this is due to Newtons III. law.

By the definition of work it is the product of the net force acting on the system and the displacement of the system so the work is 0 is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By the definition of work it is the product of the net force acting on the system and the displacement of the system so the work is 0 is it not?

This definition of work is the definition of the “net work” from the work energy theorem. It is not equal to the thermodynamic work except in the case of a point particle.

The correct definition for the thermodynamic work done by a mechanical force is the product of the force times the displacement of the material on which the force acts. Since the force acting in the piston is not zero and since the piston is moving the work on the piston is not zero. Similarly, since the force on the gas molecules is not zero and the gas molecules are moving the work on the gas is not zero.

Comment: so the definition of work from the equation: $$W_{12}=\int_1^2\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$$ cannot be applied in this case?

Comment: doesnt the bottom of the cylinder also do work on the gas?

Comment: @herosai it can be applied where $\mathbf F$ is the individual force not the net force and $\mathbf r$ is the position of the material on which the force is acting, not the center of mass. If the bottom of the cylinder is stationary then it does no work.